# How to check whether NFC is enabled or not in android?

Tags: android, nfc

How can i check whether NFC is enabled or not programmatically? Is there any way to enable the NFC on the device from my program? Please help me

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
    // adapter exists and is enabled.
}
```

You cannot enable the NFC programmatically. The user has to do it manually through settings or hardware button.

Comment: so if the returned value is FALSE, it means the device doesnt have the NFC capability, is that true @userSeven7s?

Comment: That is not correct. If the adapter is null, the device does not have NFC. Explanation on the [Developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#manifest)

Answer (score 15):

This can be done simply using the following code:

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

if (nfcAdapter == null) {
    // NFC is not available for device
} else if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    // NFC is available for device but not enabled
} else {
    // NFC is enabled
}
```

Remember that the user can turn off NFC, even while using your app.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#manifest

Although you can't programically enable NFC yourself, you can ask the user to enable it by having a button to open NFC settings like so:

```
Intent intent
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
}

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is a more complete answer which includes how to direct user to NFC settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I might be a little late here, but I've implemented a 'complete' [example](https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android/tree/master/ndeftools-util/src/org/ndeftools/util/activity/NfcDetectorActivity.java) with detection of

1. NFC capability (hardware), and
2. Initial NFC state (enabled or disabled in settings), and
3. Changes to the state

I've also added a corresponding Beam [example](https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android/tree/master/ndeftools-util/src/org/ndeftools/util/activity/NfcBeamWriterActivity.java)  which uses the

```
nfcAdapter.isNdefPushEnabled()
```

method introduced in later Android versions to detect beam state like in 2) and 3).

Comment: Can you update your answer, as Google code has shut down.

Comment: Android Beam is no longer supported.

Answer (score 8):

Use `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.nfc")`,  matching the `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"  android:required="false" />` element you should have in your manifest.

Since 2.3.3 you can also use `NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` to get the adapter (if available) and call its `isEnabled()` method to check whether NFC is currently turned on.

Answer (score 0):

```
mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
    try {
        if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
```

We can verify using NfcAdapter with context.