# How to create simple NFC program using java?

Tags: java, nfc, open-nfc

I'm a newbie learning java and nfc. Actually I really need some help about my homework "NFC programming".
I try this tutorial http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/sdk-edition/creating-a-java-example/ and I still get this error msg:

```
Start failed !
NfcException : Error while starting the NFC Manager - Caused by NFC error DRIVER
at org.opennfc.NfcManager.start(Unknown Source)
at org.opennfc.NfcManager.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at example.Example.main(Example.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.opennfc.NfcManager.stop(Unknown Source)
at example.Example.main(Example.java:36)
```

Actually, what I want to run is this example code by open-nfc

```
NfcManager mgt = NfcManager.getInstance(null);
try {
  System.out.println(mgt.getProperty("open_nfc.version"));
  System.out.println(mgt.getProperty("nfcc.firmware_version"));
} finally {
  try {
    mgt.stop();
  } catch(NfcException e) {
    System.out.println("Error :" + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

I've already start the connection center, nfc simulator, and server porting. And I have a device QPROX QP3000, already connected to my PC. I'm using eclipse juno and windows 7.

Comment: So your plan is to interact your NFC reader with some tags?

Comment: I suggest that you restructure your code so that each of the getProperty() calls are within their own try block with its own catches.  Does the getInstance() also need a try block?  Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html concerning exceptions or this tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html

Comment: @pricillia I would suggest you to try the https://github.com/grundid/nfctools, for you to get started https://github.com/grundid/nfctools-examples, it will be lot helpful.

Comment: If you have a recent Android phone, it might have an NFC reader. Check out http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/ to get started

Answer (score 1):

The line calling `NfcManager.getInstance(null)` fails. 
Are you sure that NfcManager.getInstance() requires a `null` pareameter?

After that, calling `mgt.stop()` fails again with an `java.lang.IllegalStateException`
, maybe because it's not started.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a great article [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278) (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278) through which i learned how to communicate and make payments via NFC chips.
Go through this and i hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for NfcManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcManager.html mentions calling getSystemService(NFC_SERVICE) to create the NfcManager. Also the answer to an earlier stack overflow question [How to check whether NFC is enabled or not in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618657/how-to-check-whether-nfc-is-enabled-or-not-in-android) gives a simple example code snippet. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference